# Ajax form submission url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, loopback

I have a form with fields name, email, etc. Now I want when the user clicks on the submit form get this values and submit with ajax url. How to do this. I am not using  loopback4 url as the action class and mysql as the database. Here is my code:

```
<form class="form-area contact-form text-right" name="myForm" id="myForm" action="http://localhost:3000/contacts/post" method="post"  novalidate>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
          <input name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your name'" class="common-input mb-20 form-control" required="" type="text">
          <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email address" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{1,63}$" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter email address'" class="common-input mb-20 form-control" required="" type="email">
           <div class="invalid-feedback">Please Enter a Valid Email Id.</div>
          <input name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Enter your subject" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your subject'" class="common-input mb-20 form-control" required="" type="text">
          <div class="mt-20 alert-msg" style="text-align: left;"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
          <textarea class="common-textarea form-control" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Message'" required=""></textarea>
          <button type="submit" class="primary-btn mt-20 text-white" style="float: right;">Send Message</button>
       </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Ajax:

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
        var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr('action');
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
           alert(data); // show response from the php script.
        }
        });

        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
</script>
```

If I submit, it is not inserting to the database. How to solve this.

Comment: datatype should be `dataType`

Comment: should be `onClick` event on button and inside the event call the `Ajax`

Comment: show the backend code where actual insertion happen.

Comment: @ Devsi Odedra it is with loopback4

Comment: @InzamamIdrees on submit of the form is better than on click of a button. A button submits the form but there are multiple ways to submit the form. You don’t care how they submitted it, so the click of the button is irrelevant. What is relevant is the submitting of the form.

Comment: See the post by @ﾃﾞﾋﾞｯﾄ. You mistyped one of your options. Also, you need to look at your server logs and post some of your server code because it’s quite possible that your browser is posting the ajax fine but your server isn’t processing the request properly.